# HTTPS Request : CORS error but I still get data

Tags: javascript, https, fetch

I'm making HTTPS request to a private API (hosted Itop), I get an response but I get `CORS Multiple Origin Not Allow` error so my JavaScript program can't use the response content.
I'm supposed to have CORS authorization

The requests are `POST`, made with fetch, there isn't preflight (`OPTIONS`) request made before (fetch did them alone for my other `GET` API request but didn't here)

Also some server response time is long for firefox (~2s) but it don't seems to change anything

Comment: Do you have multiple same headers or multiple values in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response?

Comment: @jabaa yes, I have 2 `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the same value

Comment: Remove one and the problem should be solved. AFAIK this is not allowed and causes this error message.

Comment: @jabaa server side I guess, I'll try, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not allowed to send multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers or multiple origins in one header in the same response. In the comments, you described two same `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers in one response. Even two same origins aren't allowed. Remove one header in the backend code.

Comment: The server only have 1 `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, I tried with firefox, edge and chrome and I still got the same error with 2 identical header

Comment: @MariusROBERT If I understand correctly, different browsers are receiving responses with a duplicate header. First, I would debug the Server-Side. You could add a dev proxy or network sniffer and analyze the communication. It's impossible to help without more details. A [mcve] of the backend could help, but this would be a new question.

Comment: I found the problem : the root "website" had one header but the endpoint I was using added one

Answer (score -2):

firefox is the best browser to identify this issue,
you can fix this issue by following this path.
when you sending a request from frontend,and then response will come from backend. but browser is not allowed to aceess to javascript. this is the cors error.

1.open ur backend, then create a package call CorsFilter.
2. and then create a filter servlet
3. paste this code

[CorsFilter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W0DY.png)

```
    @WebFilter(filterName = "CorsFilter", urlPatterns = "/*")
public class CorsFilter extends HttpFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain  chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");
        if (origin != null && origin.toLowerCase().contains(getServletContext().getInitParameter("origin"))) {
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Type");
            if (req.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
                res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD");
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you assume this is a Spring backend? I don't see any indication for it in the question.

Comment: Now, it got even worse. An image of code. You don't allow others to copy the code and expect them to retype it.

Comment: i just updated my answer for you brother !. please just checkout it. now u can copy the code. :)

Comment: I still don't understand how Java Spring code snippet helps here.